# SymmetricDS replication DDL statements

Tags: replication, ddl, symmetricds

Now I try to replicate DDL statements(like create, alter, drop) between different databases with the help of Symmetric-DS.
I've found this page https://www.symmetricds.org/docs/how-to/sync-schema-ddl-changes and found that it could be done it that way:

`bin/symadmin -e root-000 --node=001 sync-triggers`

`bin/symadmin -e root-000 --node=001 send-schema`

But, for now I cannot understand that is there possibility to replicate DDL statements automatically? I.e. I create table on one database and it creates on another automatically (without writing sync-triggers and send-schema)?
Thanks.

Comment: I have tried symadmin with sync-triggers command and send-schema command. And it is works. But I need to enter these commands every time when I want to replicate my DDL queries to target database. But I want to know maybe there is way to do this automatically(maybe with triggers or some option that I've missed).

Comment: no, there isn't a way to do it automatically unless you write a utility program that will isaue there commands