# Symmetricds: is possible transform data during the migration or syncronization?

Tags: mysql, oracle, symmetricds

I need to migrate and sync data from an oracle to mysql.
Plus I want, during the sync and migration, a data transformation because mysql has a differente table design from oracle.

I'm trying to use symmetricds for my goal, but if I understand well, symmetric can do the sync or migration, and after that you can do some transformation on table, but this operation is not automatic, you must do it by hand. Isn'it?

If I'm wrong tell me how can achive my goal with symmetricds, or if is not possible, suggest some tool for my needed.

Thanks a lot,
have a nice day

Comment: look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753824/symmetricds-replication-ddl-statements

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS transforms (extract and/or load) will fire as part of replication from source to target. So you can use them when the databases do not match on the source and target. It will be automatic as part of the normal synchronization process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I understand well, SDS cannot create automatically new tables nor new columns or last twice mixing during the migration, isn't it?

Comment: SymmetricDS can create new tables and/or alter during an initial load if the intial.load.create.first=true parameter is used.